# Why can I reach my router inside a VPN?

Tags: vpn, router

I use a third party VPN service. I tried visiting 192.168.1.1 and I'm still able to reach it. Is that subnet routed around the VPN? Why am I able to reach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VPN connects you to a new network through a virtual network interface. So technically, you still have access to the rest of the interfaces. For example, if you have an openvpn certificate on linux and connect to the network, running 'ifconfig' on a terminal will show you eth0 (enp0s3 if you are in a newer ubuntu version) and a tun0 interface, for the vpn network. You get different ip addresses for each network, but you can still "see" both, even if all your internet traffic is routed through your 3rd party vpn. After all, your connection to the vpn server has to be routed somehow from your computer to your provider.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you are able to reach it because 192.168.x.x or 192.168.1.x is your local network. This means the IP addresses within this range are accessible directly, and there is no need to use the default gateway.

You can use "route -n" on Linux to see the route map (on Windows I think it is "route print" but I can't check it now).